# Blocking JIRA status transition when review is not finished or not created

Tags: jira, atlassian-crucible

Is it possible to block **JIRA** status transition (for instance from 'In Progress' to 'Resolved'),
when there exists not empty changeset for this issue and if this changeset is not fully reviewed in Crucible - what means that not all **Crucible** reviews are closed?

Don't block otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible using Workflow Transition conditions.

I am assuming your JIRA and Crucible instances have Application Links correctly setup.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+FishEye

Using:
JIRA 5.1.1,
Crucible 3.2.2

Administration -> Project -> Workflows

You want to edit the transitions between the states that you want to block, and add conditions to it.  Each transition has a unique ID, so make sure you edit all unique transitions.  Press the Edit button to first edit the draft workflow, then in your case, click the 'Resolve Issue' transition.

Select the Conditions tab, then "Add a new condition to restrict when this transition can be performed."

If your JIRA instance is correctly linked to your Crucible instance, you should see these two conditions:

- This transition will only execute if there are no Open Crucible
  reviews related to this issue.
- This transition will only execute if
  there are no unreviewed changesets related to this issue.

Our project has these two conditions added to our Close transition to ensure a code review has been completed after an issue is resolved but before it is closed.

You then need to publish the workflow draft so that it is applied to your project.

Atlassian has more information on this:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+workflow+configuration#Advancedworkflowconfiguration-addingaconditionAddingacondition

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a custom workflow condition to me, probably best done with the Script Runner add-on

Comment: I don't think that with Script Runner I would be able to implement such a logic I mentioned (which checks the existence of reviews for changesets - only if they exist)?!